# Can't install docker-compose into jenkins dockerfile

Tags: python, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, pip

I try to install docker-compose into docker-container but it fails to build.
Here's my dockerfile:

`FROM jenkinsci/blueocean
USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache py-pip python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev rust cargo make gettext
RUN pip3 install docker-compose
USER jenkins`

And it shows me an error:

`Building wheels for collected packages: bcrypt, cryptography, pynacl, pyrsistent, PyYAML
Building wheel for bcrypt (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for bcrypt (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for bcrypt: filename=bcrypt-3.2.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=64287 sha256=4d90a6bcaa110ba58a48889ded4adb0f92fa7966ea45a8abeea0ad6f8a94004f
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/9a/0b/a2/2c559982bbee4bd184557267e5760e114de3e9ba826fe8d691
Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517): still running...
Building wheel for cryptography (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for cryptography: filename=cryptography-3.4.8-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=1360638 sha256=ef093594bbb07d34bc6de28f7447a6c257813cda8e83f5254c42d01b602351da
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/28/ea/c2/e48100a4f4674263f982c899942ed5225966b37b47e9b631f6
Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for pynacl (PEP 517): finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpi_pcnqvb
cwd: /tmp/pip-install-w50jx1wy/pynacl_e9c31de258254c47941580c85da83563
Complete output (322 lines):
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/nacl
....

subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make']' returned non-zero exit status 2.`

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pynacl
Building wheel for pyrsistent (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for pyrsistent (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for pyrsistent: filename=pyrsistent-0.18.0-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=115732 sha256=24c93c9e75844cd86f8fee6965a97c1e7068c5042b7745085d612c047cf23103
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/dd/c8/61/04c6d218b3691f75353d7f74fed3fbd40e0ee9e2d1e2ce24c6
Building wheel for PyYAML (PEP 517): started
Building wheel for PyYAML (PEP 517): finished with status 'done'
Created wheel for PyYAML: filename=PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl size=45654 sha256=231652b88a0bcee5f8b831941b4bf38a80d8815a54474f798a482a128047402b
Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/b7/a5/c4/504d913c2a55bb09c607541578ec5f844d1ff33467abe93ba5
Successfully built bcrypt cryptography pyrsistent PyYAML
Failed to build pynacl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynacl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
ERROR: Service 'jenkins' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add --no-cache py-pip python3-dev libffi-dev openssl-dev gcc libc-dev rust cargo make gettext     && pip3 install docker-compose' returned a non-zero code: 1

I was trying to upgrade/downgrade the pip but it stays the same. Please, help.

Comment: Search for "ERROR: Could not build wheels for pynacl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly".

Comment: I did it before asking. All I could find is python and environment specific problems. They advised to update/downgrade pip. Earlier I could build the container with such instructions. Now, something updated and... it's not working anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my dockerfile and it's working now. https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Docker

`FROM jenkinsci/blueocean
USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache docker-compose
USER jenkins`